# Error on build yasm/source/patched-yasm/util.h:78:23: error: libintl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, macos, makefile, android-source

After building for almost half an hour I get the following error. No amount of googling has helped so far...

```
In file included from external/chromium_org/third_party/yasm/source/patched-yasm/libyasm/phash.c:2:
external/chromium_org/third_party/yasm/source/patched-yasm/util.h:78:23: error: libintl.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/third_party_yasm_genperf_libs_host_gyp_intermediates/third_party/yasm/source/patched-yasm/libyasm/phash.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: What lunch option / device are you building for? Also what version of android are you building on?

Comment: in this case just the X86 emulator aosp_x86_64-eng  Kitkat 4.4.2

Comment: if I target aosp_arm-eng it compiles fine no errors

Comment: Obviously, libintl.h is missing. You may want to see this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11370808/1172181.

Comment: Apparently, if you install GNU gettext, it should fix your error as as the header file would be installed. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/libintl_002eh.html

Comment: It is possible that the sources of Android are not completely synchronized. Try to resync the sources and build them once again (I faced once with such type of error and this receipt helped me)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Will let everyone know which solution works

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're missing the header file you've implemented into your app. Maybe this is the Util.h file you'll need https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/chromium_org/third_party/yasm/source/patched-yasm/+/3c5fb45a0ef38ca08793c28dad3cf5be29b25f7f/util.h