# On mac, g++ (clang) fails to search /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib by default

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, clang

I'm on a mac and I used `homebrew` to install `gmp`.

```
Kyumins-iMac:gcjlib math4tots$ g++ main.cpp -lgmp -lgmpxx
In file included from main.cpp:2:
./gcjlib.hpp:4:10: fatal error: 'gmpxx.h' file not found
#include <gmpxx.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

So then I explicitly told `g++` to use `/usr/local/include`

```
Kyumins-iMac:gcjlib math4tots$ g++ main.cpp -lgmp -lgmpxx -I/usr/local/include
ld: library not found for -lgmp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So then I explicitly told `g++` to use `/usr/local/lib`

```
Kyumins-iMac:gcjlib math4tots$ g++ main.cpp -lgmp -lgmpxx -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib
Kyumins-iMac:gcjlib math4tots$ ./a.out 
sum is -4444
absolute value is 4444
```

So the only issue seems to be that `g++` fails to acknowledge `/usr/local`.

But it is tedious to type all this out all the time, especially when I'm just writing small single file programs.

Is there a way for me to get `g++` to acknowledge the stuff in `/usr/local` by default? Is there a standard way `homebrew` users do this?

---

I'm on OS X 10.9.3 with Xcode 5.1.1 in case it is relevant.

Comment: What about using a makefile?

Comment: Please stop saying `g++`, the program you are calling is `clang++` (through a confusing alias provided by apple) and your question has nothing to do with gcc. If you do install a true gcc, it is likely to work as you expect.

Comment: `$ sudo rm -rf Applications/Xcode.app` worked for me in 10.12.6.

Comment: You can use `g++ --version` to see what you're actually running.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I also use Homebrew and had a similar problem on Mac OSX Maverick 10.9.5 and Xcode 6.0.1, but it was solved by running:

`xcode-select --install`

Note that it doesn't work without the double hyphens given by the previous answer. This installs the command-line tools that also create `/usr/lib/` and `/usr/include/`. I don't know why Homebrew doesn't automatically check this upon installation, since it does check for Xcode...

If you want to check exactly what folders your compiler is looking through for header files you can write:

`cpp -v`

Comment: My hero! I've been breaking my head for the past 16 hours, solved with just one line.

Comment: Struggling to understand why Apple would stop searching /usr and /usr/local by default, but in any case, this fixes some of my build problems too.

Comment: True hero there!

Comment: I guess you meant: _This installs the command-line tools that also **search** `/usr/lib/` and `/usr/include/`_ ?

Answer (score 17):

A workaround would be to:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include
```

At least this tricked the pre-processor to behave here :)

Comment: This worked for me building nginx, although `openssl/ssl.h` was in `/opt/local/include`, so I used that path.

Comment: It might also be useful to export `LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: with cmake, `include_directories(/usr/local/include)` works too

Answer (score 11):

Try running `xcode-select --install`

At least on Mavericks, I've found that if I install the Xcode application without installing the command-line tools, then the tools are sort of available, but normal unix-ey builds don't work correctly. One symptom is that `/usr/local/include` is not on the include search path. The command-line tools seem to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have Yosemite 10.10.5 and running `xcode-select --install` didn't fix the problem for me.  The command returned with `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`.

When I ran `xcode-select -p`, it showed `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.  I ended up deleting Xcode from the Applications directory, which resulted in `xcode-select -p` returning `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`.  This fixed compiler error for me.

Comment: When I tried this, clang could no longer find some important standard library files.

Comment: It is unclear how the problem is solved from this answer, if you delete Xcode, all the compilers will be gone. For people who see this, do not try it.

Comment: If you have commandLineTools, you don't need xcode.

Answer (score 2):

That was helpful for me:

Use the latest version. `1.0.2o_1` just a current build.

```
brew install openssl
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_1/include/openssl /usr/local/include/openssl
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_1/lib /usr/local/lib/openssl
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few questions around this topic with answers that suggest putting a symlink in `/usr/local/include`. However I'm running macOS Monterey 12.3 (on an M1 MacBook) and that directory doesn't exist.

I had installed the Xcode command line tools by downloading the package from Apple, so `xcode-select --install` just tells me it's already installed and doesn't create any directories.

I ran `cpp -v` to see which directories are searched for `#include <...>`:

```
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

I picked `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include` for the symlink. In that directory, I ran the following command (note the new location for Homebrew installations, under `/opt/homebrew` - some old answers are also out of date on this point):

```bash
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include/openssl .
```

`clang` was then able to find the OpenSSL files.

Answer (score -1):

apk add --no-cache build-base
it works fine ！！！！
go  build -tags musl -o main main.go

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).