# C++ gmp and homebrew

Tags: c++, homebrew, gmp

I'm on a mac and I've installed `gcc` and `gmp` through `homebrew`.

To test out my installation I've tried out the simple example from [here](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;
int
main (void)
{
mpz_class a, b, c;

a = 1234;
b = "-5678";
c = a+b;
cout << "sum is " << c << "\n";
cout << "absolute value is " << abs(c) << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

First of all, if I try `g++ test.cpp -lgmpxx -lgmp` it complains

```
test.cpp:9:19: fatal error: gmpxx.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gmpxx.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

So I've tried `g++ test.cpp -lgmpxx -lgmp -I/usr/local/include/`

```
ld: library not found for -lgmpxx
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So then I've tried `g++ test.cpp -lgmpxx -lgmp -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/`

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, __mpz_struct const*)", referenced from:
      std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& operator<< <__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]> const&) in ccPugkZ3.o
      std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& operator<< <__mpz_struct [1], __gmp_unary_expr<__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>, __gmp_abs_function> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __gmp_unary_expr<__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>, __gmp_abs_function> > const&) in ccPugkZ3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The funny thing is that if I comment out the lines with `cout` and try `g++ test.cpp -lgmpxx -lgmp -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/ && ./a.out` there are no complaints. In particular the line `c = a+b;` didn't need to be commented out, so I feel like something seems to be happening.

What am I missing? How can I get the sample code to compile?

EDIT:

as per @Will 's suggestion, I've tried `g++ test.cpp -lgmpxx -lgmp -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -m32`

```
ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib//libgmpxx.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib//libgmpxx.dylibignoring file /usr/local/lib//libgmp.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib//libgmp.dylib

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, __mpz_struct const*)", referenced from:
      std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& operator<< <__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]> const&) in ccrPv2wC.o
      std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& operator<< <__mpz_struct [1], __gmp_unary_expr<__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>, __gmp_abs_function> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __gmp_unary_expr<__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>, __gmp_abs_function> > const&) in ccrPv2wC.o
  "___gmpz_abs", referenced from:
      __gmp_abs_function::eval(__mpz_struct*, __mpz_struct const*) in ccrPv2wC.o
  "___gmpz_add", referenced from:
      __gmp_binary_plus::eval(__mpz_struct*, __mpz_struct const*, __mpz_struct const*) in ccrPv2wC.o
  "___gmpz_clear", referenced from:
      __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::~__gmp_expr() in ccrPv2wC.o
  "___gmpz_init", referenced from:
      __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr() in ccrPv2wC.o
      __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr<__gmp_unary_expr<__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>, __gmp_abs_function> >(__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __gmp_unary_expr<__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>, __gmp_abs_function> > const&) in ccrPv2wC.o
  "___gmpz_set_si", referenced from:
      __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::assign_si(long) in ccrPv2wC.o
  "___gmpz_set_str", referenced from:
      __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::operator=(char const*) in ccrPv2wC.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I am understanding the error message correctly, it seems that the libraries were indeed built for 64-bit, and even the declaration `mpz_class a, b, c` will fail to compile with `-m32`.

Comment: Does adding the switch `-m32` help?  I don't have the env to test myself, but it could be that you've installed 32 bit libs?

Comment: @Will Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately the switch does not seem to solve the issue. I've posted the error message in an edit to my original post.

Comment: put the link path *before* the library name perhaps? `g++ -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -lgmpxx -lgmp test.cpp` (still guessing from phone)

Comment: I would try to compile by myself the same version on some custom, isolated directory, you need to grab source, then use `./configure` with `--enable-cxx` (for C++ support) and e.g. `--prefix=/home/myuser/mygmp` (for both includes and libs, eventually set `CC=gcc` and `CXX=g++`), then `make -j4`, then `make install` see if it works correctly. If so, then probably there is probably some bug within homebrew package.

Comment: Probably GMP was compiled for `clang++ -stdlib=libc++` which is a different incompatible mode.

Answer (score 1):

From this answer, try running `xcode-select --install`.

[On mac, g++ (clang) fails to search /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905661/on-mac-g-clang-fails-to-search-usr-local-include-and-usr-local-lib-by-def)

Comment: Don't know about the user, but this does not work for me on OS X 10.11.6. I think it's a bug in Apple's linker, because it does work on 10.10.5.

Comment: @JohnPerry Did you every figure out a solution? I'm still on 10.11.6 and I'm getting this error.

Comment: @John To be honest, I don't remember, but neither do I think so. For a while I was using `ports` and in order to install GNAT I had to just go ahead & remove gcc altogether.