# How to replace boost/thread/tss.hpp on Mac OSX El Capitan?

Tags: c++, boost, porting, c++03, osx-elcapitan

I recently upgraded my Mac OSX from Yosemite to El Capitan and updated Xcode to v7.1.  After the upgrades, I found that my C++ application no longer compiles due to a header file that cannot be found:

```
../../src/dir/sysArea.h:39:10: fatal error: 'boost/thread/tss.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>
```

The clang invocation is like this:

```
clang -g -std=c++11 -fno-inline -Wall -Werror -Wextra -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE   \
      -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c                       \
      -o ARCH.darwin_15_i86/debug/file.o file.cpp
```

I searched my Macintosh using the finder and the file `tss.hpp` no longer appears to be present.  How do I port my application to El Capitan, what is the replacement of Boost's `tss.hpp`?  I tried updating my Boost version from the prior v1.53 to the latest v1.58, but it had no impact, I get the same error when compiling.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
sudo chmod o+w /usr/local/opt /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib
brew unlink boost
brew install boost
sudo chmod o-w /usr/local/opt /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib
```

My C++03 application is including `tss.hpp` so that it can use the `thread_specific_ptr<>` feature:

```
static boost::thread_specific_ptr<Botan::AutoSeeded_RNG> _rng;
```

for thread local storage (e.g. each thread gets its own version of the static variable.)

---

The finder was not searching everywhere (would be nice if it did), I do have `tss.hpp` under `/usr/local/include`.

I tried adding `-stdlib=libc++` and `-stdlib=libstdc++` to the clang invocation, but neither got the complier to look in /usr/local/include for the Boost headers.  What compiler flags will instruct it to look there other than hardcoding `-I/user/local/include`?

Note that clang says `thread_local` is not available as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33358417/115751).

Comment: Also, are you willing to move to c++11?  Then you can forgo boost for this and just use `thread_local`

Comment: @donkopotamus Yeah, I'm considering that option with `thread_local` at the moment, but would still like the question answered.

Comment: Can you confirm that `boost/thread/tss.hpp` is not in `/usr/local/include` ... if not that would seem to be a problem with the `brew` installation.  (I don't use `brew`).  If it is, then are your compiler flags correct?

Comment: @donkopotamus Yes the finder was not searching there and misled me into thinking they were not present anymore.  How do I instruct the compiler to look in `/usr/local/include` in El Capitan.  Note that this was not an issue in Yosemite.

Comment: Add a `-I/usr/local/include` to your compiler flags, and you'll need to add appropriate `-L` flags to the link stage.

Comment: @donkopotamus Why were the flags not needed in Yosemite?  Shouldn't the compiler be looking there automatically instead of hard coding that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `xcode-select --install` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26404710/115751), seems to have told clang to look in the `/usr/local/include` directory for headers and resolves the issue.