# How to get support for thread_local on Mac OSX clang?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, clang, thread-local

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23850891/115751), clang from Xcode on Mac OSX does not support `thread_local` storage even with C++11 flags set.  Even on the latest version, Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76), Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0, Thread model: posix, does not support `thread_local`:

```
../../src/dir/sysArch.h:1505:3: error: thread-local storage is not supported
                                       for the current target
  thread_local
  ^
```

Comment: You could use the open source version of clang instead? I am facing the same problem. In late 2016.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of clang supplied with Xcode 8 (and later) supports the `thread_local` keyword; see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29929949/34498).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the old method of using `pthread_getspecific()` etc. to implement thread-local storage (or in Objective-C the `NSThread`'s thread dictionary) if `thread_local` is not available in your compiler version.