# openssl/ssl.h not found but installed with homebrew

Tags: c++, macos, openssl, homebrew, clang++

I am working on a C++ project on my Mac running El Capitan and I get this error even after installing openssl with Homebrew:

```
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -I../libSocket/src -I../libData/src  -c src/fsslhandler.cpp -o obj/fsslhandler.o
In file included from src/fsslhandler.cpp:1:
In file included from src/fsslhandler.h:8:
../libSocket/src/sslsocket.h:6:10: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/fsslhandler.o] Error 1
```

After searching for a solution I found one which **does not work**:

```
brew link openssl --force
```

In order to make it work, I have to add the following flags at compilation:

LDFLAGS:  `-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`

CPPFLAGS: `-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include`

**How to make it work without this flags?**

Openssl use to work on El Capitan installed with brew, but I reinstalled OS X and update openssl with homebrew and here I am.

Thank

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution: clang was not looking in the right place.

```
xcode-select --install
```

This post resolved this issue: [On mac, g++ (clang) fails to search /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905661/on-mac-g-clang-fails-to-search-usr-local-include-and-usr-local-lib-by-def)

Comment: When I run this command Mac OS tells me I already have command line tools installed.

Answer (score 22):

Try put these in your bash or zsh profile.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. All on Apple Silicon M1 and changed path /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/

Comment: @hannesach did you found solution ?

Comment: @Arti On my side all is working now. But I even can't remember exact problem

Comment: try: brew link openssl --force

Comment: I give upasdfasdf

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have openssl@3 first in your PATH, run:
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

**For compilers to find openssl@3 you may need to set:
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include"**

For pkg-config to find openssl@3 you may need to set:
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib/pkgconfig"

Answer (score 0):

based on @chouyangv3's answer, and @hannes ach's comment, this worked for me on a M1 chip under macOS 12.7:

```bash
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.8/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.8/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.8/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.8/lib/pkgconfig"
```