# 'openssl/conf.h' file not found error on MacOS Sierra

Tags: xcode, ssl, boost, cmake, homebrew

I am working on a C++ project which uses boost asio. Trying to build the libraries that use Asia,  I am getting the following error

```
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_types.hpp:19:10: fatal error: 'openssl/conf.h' file not found
#include <openssl/conf.h>
```

Looking of solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178988/openssl-ssl-h-not-found-but-installed-with-homebrew) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905661/on-mac-g-clang-fails-to-search-usr-local-include-and-usr-local-lib-by-def), I tried

```
brew install openssl
brew link openssl --force
xcode-select --install
```

But didn't help.

Doing the following also doesn't seem to work

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include
```

Boost version I am using is `boost_1_63_0`. I am on `MacOS Sierra` with `Xcode 8.3.1`. I have installed boost using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)

```
brew install boost
```

As I understand from other links, Xcode is looking at the wrong place for ssl headers. 
But **how can I resolve this?**

I looked into my `/usr/local/include` & `/opt/local/include`. 'openssl/ssl.h' is not present in either locations. But doing a `brew install openssl` says the following

```
Warning: openssl is a keg-only and another version is linked to opt.
Use `brew install --force` if you want to install this version
```

Doing a `brew install openssl --force` says

```
Warning: openssl-1.0.2k already installed, it's just not linked.
```

Doing `brew link openssl --force` also doesn't solve the issue.

Doig a `which openssl` returns the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/openssl
```

*Please suggest*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Linked or not, all installed Homebrew packages are reachable via link in `/usr/local/opt`. Additionally, when you install `openssl` via Homebrew, Homebrew tells you how to use the openssl libraries and headers.

```
~ nega@rust 15s
❯ brew install openssl
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/openssl-1.0.2k.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/nega/Library/Caches/Homebrew/openssl-1.0.2k.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring openssl-1.0.2k.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Using the sandbox
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the SystemRoots
keychain. To add additional certificates (e.g. the certificates added in
the System keychain), place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
For pkg-config to find this software you may need to set:
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k: 1,696 files, 12MB

~ nega@rust 11s
❯
```

You don't need to `brew link` anything. Just use the directories Homebrew tells you about in the appropriate places in Xcode and CMake.

Comment: well. I had to include & link to the installed location of openssl in my cmake build. thanks for the clarification @nega

Comment: @nega - Doesn't work for me, it says : openssl is a keg-only and another version is linked to opt.

Comment: @dcp what do you mean it "doesn't work"? maybe if you open a new question and link to it here, i could help out.

Comment: @nega - Thanks for your response and offer to help.  In this case, openssl was already installed (maybe as part of the OS?) and I think brew was just telling me it couldn't install it since it would conflict with the installed version.  Anyway, the installed version is working ok, so all is well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [@nega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4021251/nega) for [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43455530/1358187). I'm posting an updated version of the install message for the Apple M1 chip (Arm64) which is too long to leave as a comment on their answer unfortunately!

```
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/certs

and run
  /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/c_rehash

openssl@1.1 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS provides LibreSSL.

If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

As @nega said, you don't need to brew link anything. I exported the environment variables PATH, LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS in my bash session as recommended in the message, and then `make` worked fine for me.