# SDL2 library not found with Make but with CMake

Tags: makefile, cmake, sdl-2

I'm trying to use SDL2, SDL2_ttf, and SDL2_image in a project which uses a Makefile to build. I've tried many different methods, but no matter what I've tried so far, SDL2_ttf and SDL2_image throw errors akin to the following.

```
/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_ttf.framework/Headers/SDL_ttf.h:34:10: fatal error: 
      'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found
```

I can successfully use CMake to build the project using the following CMakeLists and values.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(kiss_sdl)


set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${kiss_sdl_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
set(BIN_DIR ${kiss_sdl_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

add_definitions(-DRESDIR=\"../../\")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR})


add_executable(kiss_sdl kiss_example1.c kiss_draw.c kiss_general.c kiss_posix.c kiss_widgets.c kiss_sdl.h)


target_link_libraries(kiss_sdl ${SDL2_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY})
install(TARGETS kiss_sdl RUNTIME DESTINATION ${BIN_DIR})
```

[image: CMake configure values]

The CMake modules I'm using to find SDL in CMake are bellow.

## FindSDL2.cmake

```
# Locate SDL2 library
# This module defines
# SDL2_LIBRARY, the name of the library to link against
# SDL2_FOUND, if false, do not try to link to SDL2
# SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR, where to find SDL.h
#
# This module responds to the the flag:
# SDL2_BUILDING_LIBRARY
# If this is defined, then no SDL2_main will be linked in because
# only applications need main().
# Otherwise, it is assumed you are building an application and this
# module will attempt to locate and set the the proper link flags
# as part of the returned SDL2_LIBRARY variable.
#
# Don't forget to include SDL2main.h and SDL2main.m your project for the
# OS X framework based version. (Other versions link to -lSDL2main which
# this module will try to find on your behalf.) Also for OS X, this
# module will automatically add the -framework Cocoa on your behalf.
#
#
# Additional Note: If you see an empty SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP in your configuration
# and no SDL2_LIBRARY, it means CMake did not find your SDL2 library
# (SDL2.dll, libsdl2.so, SDL2.framework, etc).
# Set SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP to point to your SDL2 library, and configure again.
# Similarly, if you see an empty SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY, you should set this value
# as appropriate. These values are used to generate the final SDL2_LIBRARY
# variable, but when these values are unset, SDL2_LIBRARY does not get created.
#
#
# $SDL2 is an environment variable that would
# correspond to the ./configure --prefix=$SDL2
# used in building SDL2.
# l.e.galup 9-20-02
#
# Modified by Eric Wing.
# Added code to assist with automated building by using environmental variables
# and providing a more controlled/consistent search behavior.
# Added new modifications to recognize OS X frameworks and
# additional Unix paths (FreeBSD, etc).
# Also corrected the header search path to follow "proper" SDL2 guidelines.
# Added a search for SDL2main which is needed by some platforms.
# Added a search for threads which is needed by some platforms.
# Added needed compile switches for MinGW.
#
# On OSX, this will prefer the Framework version (if found) over others.
# People will have to manually change the cache values of
# SDL2_LIBRARY to override this selection or set the CMake environment
# CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH to modify the search paths.
#
# Note that the header path has changed from SDL2/SDL.h to just SDL.h
# This needed to change because "proper" SDL2 convention
# is #include "SDL.h", not <SDL2/SDL.h>. This is done for portability
# reasons because not all systems place things in SDL2/ (see FreeBSD).
#
# Ported by Johnny Patterson. This is a literal port for SDL2 of the FindSDL.cmake
# module with the minor edit of changing "SDL" to "SDL2" where necessary. This
# was not created for redistribution, and exists temporarily pending official
# SDL2 CMake modules.
#
# Note that on windows this will only search for the 32bit libraries, to search
# for 64bit change x86/i686-w64 to x64/x86_64-w64

#=============================================================================
# Copyright 2003-2009 Kitware, Inc.
#
# CMake - Cross Platform Makefile Generator
# Copyright 2000-2014 Kitware, Inc.
# Copyright 2000-2011 Insight Software Consortium
# All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
# are met:
#
# * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
# notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#
# * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
# notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
# documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
#
# * Neither the names of Kitware, Inc., the Insight Software Consortium,
# nor the names of their contributors may be used to endorse or promote
# products derived from this software without specific prior written
# permission.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
# "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
# A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
# HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
# SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
# DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
# THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
# (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
# OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
#
# This software is distributed WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the
# implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
# See the License for more information.
#=============================================================================
# (To distribute this file outside of CMake, substitute the full
# License text for the above reference.)

FIND_PATH(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR SDL.h
    HINTS
    ${SDL2}
    $ENV{SDL2}
    PATH_SUFFIXES include/SDL2 include SDL2
    i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2
    x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2
    PATHS
    ~/Library/Frameworks
    /Library/Frameworks
    /usr/local/include/SDL2
    /usr/include/SDL2
    /sw # Fink
    /opt/local # DarwinPorts
    /opt/csw # Blastwave
    /opt
)

# Lookup the 64 bit libs on x64
IF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP SDL2
        HINTS
        ${SDL2}
        $ENV{SDL2}
        PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
        lib/x64
        x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib
        PATHS
        /sw
        /opt/local
        /opt/csw
        /opt
    )
# On 32bit build find the 32bit libs
ELSE(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP SDL2
        HINTS
        ${SDL2}
        $ENV{SDL2}
        PATH_SUFFIXES lib
        lib/x86
        i686-w64-mingw32/lib
        PATHS
        /sw
        /opt/local
        /opt/csw
        /opt
    )
ENDIF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)

IF(NOT SDL2_BUILDING_LIBRARY)
    IF(NOT ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR} MATCHES ".framework")
        # Non-OS X framework versions expect you to also dynamically link to
        # SDL2main. This is mainly for Windows and OS X. Other (Unix) platforms
        # seem to provide SDL2main for compatibility even though they don't
        # necessarily need it.
        # Lookup the 64 bit libs on x64
        IF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
            FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY
                NAMES SDL2main
                HINTS
                ${SDL2}
                $ENV{SDL2}
                PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
                lib/x64
                x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib
                PATHS
                /sw
                /opt/local
                /opt/csw
                /opt
                )
            # On 32bit build find the 32bit libs
        ELSE(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
            FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY
                NAMES SDL2main
                HINTS
                ${SDL2}
                $ENV{SDL2}
                PATH_SUFFIXES lib
                lib/x86
                i686-w64-mingw32/lib
                PATHS
                /sw
                /opt/local
                /opt/csw
                /opt
                )
        ENDIF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    ENDIF(NOT ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR} MATCHES ".framework")
ENDIF(NOT SDL2_BUILDING_LIBRARY)

# SDL2 may require threads on your system.
# The Apple build may not need an explicit flag because one of the
# frameworks may already provide it.
# But for non-OSX systems, I will use the CMake Threads package.
IF(NOT APPLE)
    FIND_PACKAGE(Threads)
ENDIF(NOT APPLE)

# MinGW needs an additional library, mwindows
# It's total link flags should look like -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lmwindows
# (Actually on second look, I think it only needs one of the m* libraries.)
IF(MINGW)
    SET(MINGW32_LIBRARY mingw32 CACHE STRING "mwindows for MinGW")
ENDIF(MINGW)

SET(SDL2_FOUND "NO")
    IF(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP)
        # For SDL2main
        IF(NOT SDL2_BUILDING_LIBRARY)
            IF(SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY)
                SET(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP ${SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP})
            ENDIF(SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY)
        ENDIF(NOT SDL2_BUILDING_LIBRARY)

        # For OS X, SDL2 uses Cocoa as a backend so it must link to Cocoa.
        # CMake doesn't display the -framework Cocoa string in the UI even
        # though it actually is there if I modify a pre-used variable.
        # I think it has something to do with the CACHE STRING.
        # So I use a temporary variable until the end so I can set the
        # "real" variable in one-shot.
        IF(APPLE)
            SET(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP ${SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP} "-framework Cocoa")
        ENDIF(APPLE)

        # For threads, as mentioned Apple doesn't need this.
        # In fact, there seems to be a problem if I used the Threads package
        # and try using this line, so I'm just skipping it entirely for OS X.
        IF(NOT APPLE)
            SET(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP ${SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
        ENDIF(NOT APPLE)

        # For MinGW library
        IF(MINGW)
            SET(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP ${MINGW32_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP})
        ENDIF(MINGW)

        # Set the final string here so the GUI reflects the final state.
        SET(SDL2_LIBRARY ${SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP} CACHE STRING "Where the SDL2 Library can be found")
        # Set the temp variable to INTERNAL so it is not seen in the CMake GUI
        SET(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP "${SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP}" CACHE INTERNAL "")

        SET(SDL2_FOUND "YES")
ENDIF(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP)

INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(SDL2 REQUIRED_VARS SDL2_LIBRARY SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

## FindSDL2_ttf.cmake

```
# Locate SDL2_ttf library
# This module defines
# SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY, the name of the library to link against
# SDL2_TTF_FOUND, if false, do not try to link to SDL2_ttf
# SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR, where to find SDL_image.h
#
# Additional Note: If you see an empty SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP in your configuration
# and no SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY, it means CMake did not find your SDL2_Image library
# (SDL2_ttf.dll, libsdl2_image.so, SDL2_ttf.framework, etc).
# Set SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP to point to your SDL2 library, and configure again.
# Similarly, if you see an empty SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY, you should set this value
# as appropriate. These values are used to generate the final SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY
# variable, but when these values are unset, SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY does not get created.
#
# $SDL2 is an environment variable that would
# correspond to the ./configure --prefix=$SDL2
# used in building SDL2.
# l.e.galup 9-20-02
#
# Modified by Eric Wing.
# Added code to assist with automated building by using environmental variables
# and providing a more controlled/consistent search behavior.
# Added new modifications to recognize OS X frameworks and
# additional Unix paths (FreeBSD, etc).
# Also corrected the header search path to follow "proper" SDL2 guidelines.
# Added a search for SDL2main which is needed by some platforms.
# Added a search for threads which is needed by some platforms.
# Added needed compile switches for MinGW.
#
# On OSX, this will prefer the Framework version (if found) over others.
# People will have to manually change the cache values of
# SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY to override this selection or set the CMake environment
# CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH to modify the search paths.
#
# Note that the header path has changed from SDL2/SDL.h to just SDL.h
# This needed to change because "proper" SDL2 convention
# is #include "SDL.h", not <SDL2/SDL.h>. This is done for portability
# reasons because not all systems place things in SDL2/ (see FreeBSD).
#
# Ported by Johnny Patterson. This is a literal port for SDL2 of the FindSDL.cmake
# module with the minor edit of changing "SDL" to "SDL2" where necessary. This
# was not created for redistribution, and exists temporarily pending official
# SDL2 CMake modules.
# 
# Note that on windows this will only search for the 32bit libraries, to search
# for 64bit change x86/i686-w64 to x64/x86_64-w64

#=============================================================================
# Copyright 2003-2009 Kitware, Inc.
#
# CMake - Cross Platform Makefile Generator
# Copyright 2000-2014 Kitware, Inc.
# Copyright 2000-2011 Insight Software Consortium
# All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
# are met:
#
# * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
# notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#
# * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
# notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
# documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
#
# * Neither the names of Kitware, Inc., the Insight Software Consortium,
# nor the names of their contributors may be used to endorse or promote
# products derived from this software without specific prior written
# permission.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
# "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
# A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
# HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
# SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
# DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
# THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
# (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
# OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
#
# This software is distributed WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the
# implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
# See the License for more information.
#=============================================================================
# (To distribute this file outside of CMake, substitute the full
# License text for the above reference.)

FIND_PATH(SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR SDL_ttf.h
    HINTS
    ${SDL2}
    $ENV{SDL2}
    $ENV{SDL2_TTF}
    PATH_SUFFIXES include/SDL2 include SDL2
    i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2
    PATHS
    ~/Library/Frameworks
    /Library/Frameworks
    /usr/local/include/SDL2
    /usr/include/SDL2
    /sw # Fink
    /opt/local # DarwinPorts
    /opt/csw # Blastwave
    /opt
)

# Lookup the 64 bit libs on x64
IF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP
        NAMES SDL2_ttf
        HINTS
        ${SDL2}
        $ENV{SDL2}
        $ENV{SDL2_TTF}
        PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
        lib/x64
        x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib
        PATHS
        /sw
        /opt/local
        /opt/csw
        /opt
    )
# On 32bit build find the 32bit libs
ELSE(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP
        NAMES SDL2_ttf
        HINTS
        ${SDL2}
        $ENV{SDL2}
        $ENV{SDL2_TTF}
        PATH_SUFFIXES lib
        lib/x86
        i686-w64-mingw32/lib
        PATHS
        /sw
        /opt/local
        /opt/csw
        /opt
    )
ENDIF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)

SET(SDL2_TTF_FOUND "NO")
    IF(SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP)
    # Set the final string here so the GUI reflects the final state.
    SET(SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP} CACHE STRING "Where the SDL2_ttf Library can be found")
    # Set the temp variable to INTERNAL so it is not seen in the CMake GUI
    SET(SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP "${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
    SET(SDL2_TTF_FOUND "YES")
ENDIF(SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY_TEMP)

INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(SDL2_TTF REQUIRED_VARS SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

## FindSDL2_image.cmake

```
# Locate SDL2_image library
# This module defines
# SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY, the name of the library to link against
# SDL2_IMAGE_FOUND, if false, do not try to link to SDL2_image
# SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR, where to find SDL_image.h
#
# Additional Note: If you see an empty SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY_TEMP in your configuration
# and no SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY, it means CMake did not find your SDL2_Image library
# (SDL2_image.dll, libsdl2_image.so, SDL2_image.framework, etc).
# Set SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY_TEMP to point to your SDL2 library, and configure again.
# Similarly, if you see an empty SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY, you should set this value
# as appropriate. These values are used to generate the final SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY
# variable, but when these values are unset, SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY does not get created.
#
# $SDL2 is an environment variable that would
# correspond to the ./configure --prefix=$SDL2
# used in building SDL2.
# l.e.galup 9-20-02
#
# Modified by Eric Wing.
# Added code to assist with automated building by using environmental variables
# and providing a more controlled/consistent search behavior.
# Added new modifications to recognize OS X frameworks and
# additional Unix paths (FreeBSD, etc).
# Also corrected the header search path to follow "proper" SDL2 guidelines.
# Added a search for SDL2main which is needed by some platforms.
# Added a search for threads which is needed by some platforms.
# Added needed compile switches for MinGW.
#
# On OSX, this will prefer the Framework version (if found) over others.
# People will have to manually change the cache values of
# SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY to override this selection or set the CMake environment
# CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH to modify the search paths.
#
# Note that the header path has changed from SDL2/SDL.h to just SDL.h
# This needed to change because "proper" SDL2 convention
# is #include "SDL.h", not <SDL2/SDL.h>. This is done for portability
# reasons because not all systems place things in SDL2/ (see FreeBSD).
#
# Ported by Johnny Patterson. This is a literal port for SDL2 of the FindSDL.cmake
# module with the minor edit of changing "SDL" to "SDL2" where necessary. This
# was not created for redistribution, and exists temporarily pending official
# SDL2 CMake modules.
# 
# Note that on windows this will only search for the 32bit libraries, to search
# for 64bit change x86/i686-w64 to x64/x86_64-w64

#=============================================================================
# Copyright 2003-2009 Kitware, Inc.
#
# CMake - Cross Platform Makefile Generator
# Copyright 2000-2014 Kitware, Inc.
# Copyright 2000-2011 Insight Software Consortium
# All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
# are met:
#
# * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
# notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#
# * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
# notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
# documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
#
# * Neither the names of Kitware, Inc., the Insight Software Consortium,
# nor the names of their contributors may be used to endorse or promote
# products derived from this software without specific prior written
# permission.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
# "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
# A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
# HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
# SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
# DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
# THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
# (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
# OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
#
# This software is distributed WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the
# implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
# See the License for more information.
#=============================================================================
# (To distribute this file outside of CMake, substitute the full
# License text for the above reference.)

FIND_PATH(SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR SDL_image.h
    HINTS
    ${SDL2}
    $ENV{SDL2}
    $ENV{SDL2_IMAGE}
    PATH_SUFFIXES include/SDL2 include SDL2
    i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2
    x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2
    PATHS
    ~/Library/Frameworks
    /Library/Frameworks
    /usr/local/include/SDL2
    /usr/include/SDL2
    /sw # Fink
    /opt/local # DarwinPorts
    /opt/csw # Blastwave
    /opt
)

# Lookup the 64 bit libs on x64
IF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY_TEMP
        NAMES SDL2_image
        HINTS
        ${SDL2}
        $ENV{SDL2}
        $ENV{SDL2_IMAGE}
        PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
        lib/x64
        x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib
        PATHS
        /sw
        /opt/local
        /opt/csw
        /opt
    )
# On 32bit build find the 32bit libs
ELSE(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY_TEMP
        NAMES SDL2_image
        HINTS
        ${SDL2}
        $ENV{SDL2}
        $ENV{SDL2_IMAGE}
        PATH_SUFFIXES lib
        lib/x86
        i686-w64-mingw32/lib
        PATHS
        /sw
        /opt/local
        /opt/csw
        /opt
    )
ENDIF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)

SET(SDL2_IMAGE_FOUND "NO")
    IF(SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY_TEMP)
    # Set the final string here so the GUI reflects the final state.
    SET(SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY_TEMP} CACHE STRING "Where the SDL2_image Library can be found")
    # Set the temp variable to INTERNAL so it is not seen in the CMake GUI
    SET(SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY_TEMP "${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY_TEMP}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
    SET(SDL2_IMAGE_FOUND "YES")
ENDIF(SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY_TEMP)

INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(SDL2_IMAGE REQUIRED_VARS SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Following is the makefile, then some of the different methods I've tried. I have removed some irrelevant code from the makefile to make it more clear, please see the full code [on GitHub](https://github.com/actsl/kiss_sdl/blob/master/kiss_makefile).

```
#CPP = clang++
#C = clang
CPP = g++
C = gcc

### Macintosh

LDFLAGS = -L/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework \
-L/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_ttf.framework \
-L/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework \
-lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf
CFLAGS = -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers \
-I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_ttf.framework/Headers \
-I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework/Headers \
-Wall -c -std=c89
EXE1 = kiss_example1
EXE2 = kiss_example2

### Linux

#LDFLAGS = -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf
#CFLAGS = -Wall -c -std=c89
#EXE1 = kiss_example1
#EXE2 = kiss_example2

all: $(EXE1) $(EXE2)

$(EXE1): kiss_example1.o kiss_widgets.o kiss_draw.o kiss_general.o \
kiss_posix.o
    $(C) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

$(EXE2): kiss_example2.o kiss_widgets.o kiss_draw.o kiss_general.o \
kiss_posix.o
    $(C) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

kiss_example1.o: kiss_example1.c
    $(C) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

kiss_example2.o: kiss_example2.c
    $(C) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

kiss_widgets.o: kiss_widgets.c
    $(C) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

kiss_draw.o: kiss_draw.c
    $(C) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

kiss_general.o: kiss_general.c
    $(C) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

kiss_posix.o: kiss_posix.c
    $(C) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm *.o && rm $(EXE1) && rm $(EXE2)
#   del *.o
#   del $(EXE1)
#   del $(EXE2)
```

1.

```
LDFLAGS = -framework SDL -framework SDL_ttf -framework SDL_image
CFLAGS = -framework SDL -framework SDL_ttf -framework SDL_image \
-Wall -c -std=c89
EXE1 = kiss_example1
EXE2 = kiss_example2
```

2.

```
LDFLAGS = -framework SDL -framework SDL_ttf -framework SDL_image
CFLAGS = -framework SDL -framework SDL_ttf -framework SDL_image \
-I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers \
-I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_ttf.framework/Headers \
-I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework/Headers \
-Wall -c -std=c89
EXE1 = kiss_example1
EXE2 = kiss_example2
```

3.

```
LDFLAGS = -framework SDL -framework SDL_ttf -framework SDL_image
CFLAGS = -Wall -c -std=c89
EXE1 = kiss_example1
EXE2 = kiss_example2
```

The full project I'm trying to build is KISS_SDL, which can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/actsl/kiss_sdl).

Comment: The first thing to check - which directory **should be included**, for make `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` work. Try to find this file under directories specified in `*_INCLUDE_DIR` variables.

Comment: @usr1234567 It is specific to the OSX operating environment, though; are you sure it shouldn't be used? Someone well-versed in Make, but only on Windows may be unable to answer this question. Similarly, someone who hasn't used Make, but knows OSX Framework Bundles inside and out could spot a simple error in naming or something.

Comment: @usr1234567 Ah, I see, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

`CMake` and `make` serve entirely different, albeit related, purposes.  `CMake` analyzes the system on which it is running in light of the requirements given by the various `CMakeLists.txt` files, and constructs a `Makefile`.  You then perform the actual build via `make`.  `CMake`'s role is similar to that of a traditional `configure` script, and especially like the configure scripts produced by GNU Autoconf.

So how does `CMake` discover the location of the SDL2 headers?  It has a small script somewhere on the system that knows how to do it.  Several, actually.  (Hundreds of these are included in a CMake installation, and a software distributor can provide their own as well.)  It may use `pkg-config`, as the other answer suggests you do yourself, or it may test several common locations, or it may use some other facility.  Your `CMakeLists.txt` invokes three of these and instructs CMake how to use the results with these lines:

```
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

You can probably determine what `CMake` is actually doing by examining the corresponding cmake scripts.  On my Linux system they would be

```
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindSDL.cmake
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindSDL_ttf.cmake
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindSDL_image.cmake
```

Where you would find them on your Mac depends on details of how `CMake` is installed.

Alternatively, you can examine the `Makefile` generated by `CMake`.  It will be rather more complicated than yours, but you should be able to determine which flags are being passed to the compiler and linker.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Indeed, CMake is able to find SDL2 only because of the FindSDL2.cmake files I included in /cmake directory. These are files I found on the internet (I think from http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php ). I have examined all three of them, as well as the makefile generated by CMake, however I'm still not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I will add the .cmake files to my answer in case you or someone else would like to see them, but I think the issue is more about my inexperience with Make, rather than some wizardry by CMake. I'll take another look, though. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason is written as a comment in each `FindSDL*.cmake` script you show:

> Note that the header path has changed from SDL2/SDL.h to just SDL.h

Probably, you use headers from incompatible version of libraries `SDL` and `SDL_ttf`: the first one provides main header as `SDL.h`, but the second one expects it to be `SDL2/SDL2.h`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I considered this, but since everything works with CMake, I'm not sure that the libraries are incompatible. It is probably possible that CMake does something weird, like duplicate the libraries to create a new file structure, but if that's the case, surely I can do it with Make, too? I'll double check to see if there are new library versions.

Comment: @MichaelBethke: No, CMake never does weird things. Especially not such weird things you are describing. Run your CMake-generated make file with `VERBOSE=1` to get the call. Then you can compare it to your own make file.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `pkg-config` to discover header and library locations. This should work using `GNU make`:

```
SDL2_CXXFLAGS := \
    $(shell pkg-config sdl2 --cflags) \
    $(shell pkg-config SDL2_ttf --cflags) \
    $(shell pkg-config SDL2_image --cflags)

SDL2_LDFLAGS := \
    $(shell pkg-config sdl2 --libs) \
    $(shell pkg-config SDL2_ttf --libs) \
    $(shell pkg-config SDL2_image --libs)
```

I have not used `pkg-config` on `Windows` but apparently it is available.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with SDL2, which I fixed by following the directions in these answers:

[On mac, g++ (clang) fails to search /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905661/on-mac-g-clang-fails-to-search-usr-local-include-and-usr-local-lib-by-def)

OSX seems to override the include and lib paths by default for some reason.

Comment: Using the answers provided in that question (installing a duplicate Xcode command line tools), I am able to use my original Makefile, with minor modifications, to build the project. Thank you very much for the help. However, CMake is able to build the project without this, so I'd like to seek a solution which would not require other developers to go through this extra step. I really do appreciate your answer, though, thanks!

Comment: I don't really work with CMake, but as I understand, it generates some sort of build scripts or Makefiles. You could have a look at those and see what kind of magic sauce they're using. I suspect they look in several locations for the libraries and includes, and then use the first one that works.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to write the makefile:

Since you makefile is named `kiss_makefile` the following make file would be executed via:

```
make -f kiss_makefile
```

and now the makefile contents:

```
CPP := /bin/g++
C   := /bin/gcc
RM  := /bin/rm


C_FLAGS_32 := -D32_BIT \
    -IC:\SDL2-2.0.4\include \
    -IC:\SDL2-2.0.4\i686-w64-mingw32\include \
    -IC:\SDL2_ttf-2.0.14\i686-w64-mingw32\include \
    -IC:\SDL2_image-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32\include \
    -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -c -std=gnu99 -m32 -march=i686

C_FLAGS_64 := -D64_BIT \
    -IC:\SDL2-2.0.4\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include \
    -IC:\SDL2_ttf-2.0.14\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include \
    -IC:\SDL2_image-2.0.1\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include \
    -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -c -std=gnu99

L_FLAGS_32 := \
    -LC:\SDL2-2.0.4\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib \
    -LC:\SDL2_ttf-2.0.14\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib \
    -LC:\SDL2_image-2.0.1\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib \
    -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf \
    -mwindows

L_FLAGS_64 := \
    -LC:\SDL2-2.0.4\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib \
    -LC:\SDL2_ttf-2.0.14\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib \
    -LC:\SDL2_image-2.0.1\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib \
    -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf \
    -mwindows

ARCH := $(shell getconf LONG_BIT)

CFLAGS := C_FLAGS_$(ARCH)

LFLAGS := L_FLAGS_$(ARCH)

SRC1 := kiss_example1.c kiss_widgets.c kiss_draw.c kiss_general.o kiss_posix.c
OBJ1 := $(SRC1:.c=.o)

SRC2 := kiss_example2.c kiss_widgets.c kiss_draw.c kiss_general.o kiss_posix.c
OBJ2 := $(SRC2:.c=.o)

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXE1) $(EXE2)

$(EXE1): $(OBJ1)
<tab>$(C) $^  -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(EXE2): $(OBJ2)
<tab>$(C) $^  -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o:%.c
<tab>$(C) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@


.PHONY: clean
clean:
<tab>rm *.o
<tab>rm $(EXE1)
<tab>rm $(EXE2)
```

Notice the proper indication to `make` that certain targets: `all` and `clean` do not produce a file of the same name

Notice the generic rule/recipe for compiling each source file into an object file.

Note: the reason for the 3 macros `C`, `RM`, and `CPP` are so the correct file of that name is executed.  Therefore, those macros include the path to the correct file.

Notice the compile parameter `-D32_BIT` and `-D64_BIT` are something you can use, if the source code needs to perform something different, depending on the underlying architecture.

Notice where the answer says `<tab>`, in the actual makefile, replace with an actual tab character

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm sorry, I may not even know enough about Make to use your code correctly, but I replaced my kiss_makefile with this, and now using `make -f kiss_makefile` returns `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'`. Should I try to merge the two files somehow?

Comment: the 'all' target is saying that the two executables are to be generated.  If nothing in the source files/header files has been updated since the last time the executables were generated, then 'naturally' there is nothing to do.  You could try making some edit to one of the source files Then the associated work will be re-done by 'make'.    I hope you do know that the 'make' facility was so that unneeded operations are not repeated. Back when a compile could take hours and hours, the 'make' facility was a godsend.  Today, it is more used to organize all the needed operations for repeatability.

Comment: I do know that usually when Make says there's nothing to be done for all, there are no changes to build, however in this case, it hasn't built anything. It looks like you might be targeting MinGW in all of these, so maybe this Makefile is written exclusively for Windows (I'm not using Windows, so maybe that'd explain it)? Sorry, I'm still trying to learn about Make, so please forgive my ignorance. Thanks!