# Errors when trying to use secp256k1 on Mac. 'clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'

Tags: c, macos, secp256k1

I'm starting learning C, but I seem to have failed in installing my first library. I'm using a Mac.

I found a simple tutorial to get started: writing a [program to generate cryptographic keys](https://nickfarrow.com/Cryptography-in-Bitcoin-with-C/).

It uses the [secp256k1](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1) library.

I installed the library and copied the first couple of lines from the tutorial.

```
#include <secp256k1.h>
static secp256k1_context *ctx = NULL;
ctx = secp256k1_context_create(
            SECP256K1_CONTEXT_SIGN | SECP256K1_CONTEXT_VERIFY);;
```

But when I `make` my C program, I get this error:

```
cc     keyGen.c   -o keyGen
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_secp256k1_context_create", referenced from:
      _main in keyGen-50d772.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [keyGen] Error 1
```

Here's a breakdown of how I installed secp256k1.

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make check
$ sudo make install
```

I get no errors with this. Only when I `make` the program.

I've found a [threads with the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177958/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-for-library-using-cgo-on-macos-sier), but I still can't seem to get it working. Perhaps it's different for Mac (they use Linux), but more likely it's because I haven't understood what it means. They speak very generally, I'm not sure I'm inputting the specific commands correctly.

The question I linked suggested to run `./configure --enable-module-recovery`. I have also trying to install it using this, but it didn't work either.

The question then goes on to talk about defining paths and modifying `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`, however, this for another program `cgo`. I can't work out what I need to modify, as this my own program it won't work in.

If anyone could give me some suggestions what I need to do that would be great.

Comment: You need to add the relevant library to the link line.  That might be `-lsecp256k1` or something else.  The documentation should tell.  You might need to specify the library location too with `-L/opt/secp256k1/lib` or something similar, though it is probably necessary since header was found.