# cmake on mac fails to find /usr/local/include (libevhtp)

Tags: macos, makefile, cmake, include, libevent

I am trying to compile `libevhtp` (https://github.com/criticalstack/libevhtp) on my mac (10.13.3), but the `cmake` process does not seem to consider `/usr/local/include` (and thus wont find the required `libevent` headers):

```
16:43:42 me:~/Development/libevhtp/build> cmake -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include ..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 9.1.0.9020039
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 9.1.0.9020039
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Could NOT find ONIGURUMA (missing:  ONIGURUMA_LIBRARY ONIGURUMA_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Looking for strndup
-- Looking for strndup - found
-- Looking for strnlen
-- Looking for strnlen - found
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h - found
-- Looking for include file string.h
-- Looking for include file string.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdint.h
-- Looking for include file stdint.h - found
-- Looking for include file errno.h
-- Looking for include file errno.h - found
-- Looking for include file strings.h
-- Looking for include file strings.h - found
-- Looking for include file inttypes.h
-- Looking for include file inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for include file limits.h
-- Looking for include file limits.h - found
-- Looking for include file unistd.h
-- Looking for include file unistd.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdarg.h
-- Looking for include file stdarg.h - found
-- Looking for include file sys/tree.h
-- Looking for include file sys/tree.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sys/queue.h
-- Looking for include file sys/queue.h - found
-- Looking for include file sys/un.h
-- Looking for include file sys/un.h - found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of int
-- Check size of int - done
-- Check size of long
-- Check size of long - done
-- Check size of short
-- Check size of short - done
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Performing Test has_c99
-- Performing Test has_c99 - Success
-- Performing Test has_stack_protector
-- Performing Test has_stack_protector - Success
```

...

```
-- Found LIBEVENT: /usr/local/lib/libevent.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libevent_openssl.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libevent_core.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libevent_extra.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libevent_pthreads.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libevent_extra.dylib
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing:  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Could NOT find ONIGURUMA (missing:  ONIGURUMA_LIBRARY ONIGURUMA_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- ONIGURUMA NOT FOUND, DISABLING REGEX SUPPORT
```

Trying to compile:

```
16:51:34 me:~/Development/libevhtp/build> make
[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/evhtp.dir/evhtp.c.o
/Users/myself/Development/libevhtp/evhtp.c:30:10: fatal error: 'event2/dns.h' file not found
#include <event2/dns.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/evhtp.dir/evhtp.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/evhtp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

But the file exists:

```
16:51:36 me:~/Development/libevhtp/build> ll /usr/local/include/event2/dns.h
-rw-r--r--  1 myself  admin    26K Jan 26  2017 /usr/local/include/event2/dns.h
```

I am not familiar with cmake, so I don't know how to fix this. I tried `cmake -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include ..` but it didn.t help.

Comment: Looks like, `CMakeLists.txt` of given project doesn't add `/usr/local/include` into include directories (probably, project's bug). And on MacOS `/usr/local/include` [doesn't searched by a compiler by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905661/on-mac-g-clang-fails-to-search-usr-local-include-and-usr-local-lib-by-def).

Comment: Thanks for linking that issue. If you post it as a reply I can accept it, because as stated in the linked topic, doing `xcode-select --install` just completely resolved the issue.