# Linking not working in homebrew's cmake since Mojave

Tags: c++, cmake, homebrew

I've reproduced this symptom on two computers now, `cmake` seems to no longer look in `/usr/local/lib` (or more properly, `$(brew --prefix)/lib`) for Homebrew-provided libraries since upgrading my machine to macOS Mojave.

Although there are ways to circumvent this (e.g. search for homebrew prefix using `EXECUTE_PROCESS`; add the result to `LINK_LIBRARIES(...)` command) none are ideal.  What changed in Mojave to break this behavior?

The temporary workaround is to add the following to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# WARNING: Don't hard-code this path
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/lib)
```

I've already tried `brew doctor` and updated all homebrew packages to no avail.

The specific error that `cmake` (`make`) shows is:

```
ld: library not found for -l<somelib>
```

I've [asked the question on the Homebrew forums](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/cmake-linking-not-working-since-mojave/3790) and the [Apple developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/345772).

Comment: I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34780341/3196753) explaining how to list the linker search paths using `ld -v 2`.  On High Sierra, it lists `/usr/local/lib` in the default linker path.  Need to compare against Mojave.

Comment: ... update, Mojave also has `/usr/local/lib` in the default linker path.

Comment: Only after adding `VERBOSE=1` to `make` and comparing the exact linker flags between 10.13 and 10.14 was I able to track it down to a new `-isysroot` flag being added.  Here's a detailed discussion about it on MacPorts https://trac.macports.org/ticket/57612

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've isolated this to the following change in the `VERBOSE=1 make` logs...

- High Sierra (<=10.13) and below did **NOT** use the `-isysroot` command.
- Mojave (>=10.14) **DOES** use the `-isysroot` command.

From [gnu.org](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html):

> `-isysroot <dir>`
>   This option is like the `--sysroot` option, but applies only to header files (**except for Darwin targets, where it applies to both header files and libraries**). See the `--sysroot` option for more information.

So this flag specifically clobbers the `lib` search path only on Apple.  This results in the compilation never looking in the standard `ld` locations, which can be seen by typing `ld -v dummy`.

```
Library search paths:
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
```

Why does `cmake` do this?  My thought is it was to fix the [`/usr/local/include` issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519492) introduced with the new Mojave SDK behavior.

Unfortunately, I can't find a `cmake` compile flag to add the default library search paths back in.  For now the only solution I've found is to add the following to my project:

```
IF(APPLE)
    # Fix linking on 10.14+. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54068035
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/lib)
ENDIF()
```

I'm not sure if this is a behavior that warrants an upstream `cmake` patch.  If there is a better solution, please provide it.

Comment: Thanks for this., This is gviing me issue installing wireshark. Where do i add the code?

Comment: If you're building from source, I'd guess `CMakeLists.txt`, but I'm not familiar with the code base.  If you're installing from something like MacPorts or Homebrew, it may need to go into a patch file, or perhaps as a submission to the Wireshark codereview process.  https://code.wireshark.org/review/#/q/status:open.  Wireshark is super popular so it's probably worthy of a dedicated question here, or on the Wireshark bug tracker.

Answer (score 10):

Ran into a related (?) issue while trying to `pip install psycopg2` in a Django app under OS X Mojave (10.14). I was getting the following errors:

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

> The short explanation: « As of High Sierra, /usr/local is no longer
>   chown-able... »
>
> The solution: [change permissions for /usr/local to allow Homebrew to
>   create links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53752569/2162844).

I adapted the solution to my needs. Then I was finally able to run `pip install psycopg2`. Here is the sequence of commands (**update**: inside your project root i.e. where you see manage.py).

First

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Then

```
brew reinstall openssl
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: Settings LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS seems to have fixed the issue without chowning /usr/local
Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Thank you! I had this exact same issue. It was driving me crazy.