# 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found with CMake

Tags: cmake, sfml

With SFML installed on a Mac, I have some source files set up dependent on SFML such that I can compile them using the following command:

```
g++  src/*  --std=c++20 -l sfml-system -l sfml-window -l sfml-graphics
```

Anyway, I'm trying to build the project using CMake, but I keep getting this error

```
`'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -g ")

project(silentValley)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS  src/*.cpp)

add_library(silentValleyLib SHARED ${SRC_FILES})

# BLOCK 1
# target_include_directories(silentValleyLib PUBLIC
#     /usr/local/include/SFML/sfml-system
#     /usr/local/include/SFML/sfml-window
#     /usr/local/include/SFML/sfml-graphics
#     /usr/local/include/SFML/
# )


# BlOCK2
# target_compile_options(silentValleyLib PRIVATE "-l sfml-system -l sfml-window -l sfml-graphics")

add_executable(silentValley ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(silentValley PRIVATE
    silentValleyLib
)
```

Because of how I am able to compile using g++, I would expect this to work. Including the first commented block of code does nothing, and adding the second fails as well providing the warning

```
 warning: -l sfml-system -l sfml-window -l sfml-graphics: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

Can someone help me understand how to set this up ?

Comment: The directory `/usr/local/include` is not used as include directory on MacOS  by default: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905661/on-mac-g-clang-fails-to-search-usr-local-include-and-usr-local-lib-by-def. As for libraries to link, in CMake they are specified by `target_link_libraries` command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136418/how-to-add-l-ell-compiler-flag-in-cmake/43136695#43136695

Comment: Did you try to add `pkg_check_modules (SFML REQUIRED sfml-all)` command to CMakeLists.txt? Your local include directory might not be a default path to look for includes.

Comment: Yes actually target_link_libraries is what I initially used but it did not work
`
target_link_libraries(silentValleyLib PUBLIC
    /usr/local/include/SFML/sfml-system
    /usr/local/include/SFML/sfml-window
    /usr/local/include/SFML/sfml-graphics
    /usr/local/include/SFML/
    # ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR}
    # SFML
    sfml-system
    sfml-window
    sfml-graphics
)
`

Comment: pkg_check_modules is unknown to Cmake although I'm using 3.24.2. Still trying to figure this out

Comment: @Tsyvarev For me it seems included by default. Therefore I'm not sure why I have to specify target_link_libraries. I still specify it, but with no success

Comment: Sorry, I thought you are familiar with CMake. The actual command is `find_package (PkgConfig REQUIRED)` and then in a new line you add `pkg_check_modules (SFML REQUIRED sfml-all)`

Comment: I had to target_link_libraries to /Library/Frameworks/SFML.framework to advance to linking phase, but it fails. Although this question seems imply that target_link_libraries should be equivalent to -l https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136418/how-to-add-l-ell-compiler-flag-in-cmake/43136695#43136695

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this path with target_link_libraries to make it work

````
target_link_libraries(silentValleyLib
    /Library/Frameworks/SFML.framework
    /Library/Frameworks/sfml-system.framework/sfml-system
    /Library/Frameworks/sfml-window.framework/sfml-window
    /Library/Frameworks/sfml-graphics.framework/sfml-graphics
)```
````